# Proving that $Z(G)$ has an element of order $2$ if $|G| = 76$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am trying to solve the following question. I think I have a solution; but this problem was on a first year PhD exam at a university, and I think my solution is too long. Is there another solution, or is there a way to improve my solution?

> Let $G$ be a group of order $76 = 4 \cdot 19$. Prove that $Z(G)$ has an element of order $2$.

**Idea 1 (incomplete):** If we could just prove that the center of $G$ is non-trivial, we would be done; for if we assume $|Z(G)|$ is $19$ then we can actually prove $G$ is abelian, (since $G = PQ$ where $P, Q$ are 2-Sylows and 19-Sylows), and if $Z(G)=2$ or $4$, we are done even quicker. But I don't know how to prove that $Z(G)$ is nontrivial. I tried the class equation but no success.

**Solution (semidirect products):** Using Sylow Theorems, we can prove that the 19 Sylow is normal; call it $H$. Let $K$ be the 2-Sylow of order $4$. Then $G = H \rtimes_{\phi} K$.

**Case 1:** $K \cong Z_4$

Let $k$ be a generator for $K$, and $h$ a generator for $H$.

We have $\text{Aut(H)} \cong (\mathbb{Z}/19\mathbb{Z})^{\times} = \langle 2 \rangle$ (cyclic of order 18). The only homomorphisms from $K \to (\mathbb{Z}/19\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ are the trivial homomorphism $\phi_1$, and the homomorphism $\phi_2$ which maps $k \mapsto 2^9 = 18$. The homomorphism $\phi_2$ corresponds to mapping $k$ to the automorphism of $H$ given by $h \mapsto h^{18} = h^{-1}$.

Now $(1, k^2)$ is an element of order $2$ and I claim that it is in the center by showing it commutes with $(h, 1)$ and $(1, k)$ which are generators of $G$. The element $(1, k^2)$ certainly commutes with $(1, k)$.

Since $k$ sends $h \mapsto h^{-1}$, we have that $k^2$ sends $h \mapsto h$.

Now

$$(1, k^2)(h, 1) = (1 k^2 \cdot h, k^2)= (h, k^2)$$

$$(h, 1)(1, k^2) = (h, k^2)$$

**Case 2:** $K \cong Z_2 \times Z_2$

Haven't worked out the details in this case, but I assume it works similarly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you showed, the is only one non-trivial involutory automorphism of $Z_{19}$ (namely $x\mapsto x^{-1}$).

As the $2$-Sylow has four elements, it is abelian and in both possible cases, we can enumerate its elements as $1,a,b,ab$. If both $a$ and $b$ acts as non-trivial involution on  $Z_{19}$, then $ab$ must act as identity. At any rate, one of $a,b,ab$ acts as identity and we have found a central element of order $2$ (or perhaps $4$).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative proof is given by using the classification of groups of order $4p$ with $p\equiv 3\bmod 4$ (respectively $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$). The groups are
$$
C_{4p},D_{2p},Q_p, C_p\times V_4,
$$
and  all these groups have an element of order $2$ in their center. See Proposition 2.1 [here](http://math.bu.edu/people/tkohl/mathematics/4p.pdf) for the details, or [Ask a Topologist](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_an_algebraist_2008&task=show_msg&msg=2882.0001.0001.0002).